# Flutter is not showing me the suggestion window for color names/numbers in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'd like to be able to see a suggestion that will allow me to see what colour belongs to which colour name/number when using Android studio.

Please note that "Show quick documentation on mouse move" has been activated in my Android studio general settings.

[This is what my screen looks like when my mouse is on "blueGrey"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGIii.png)

[This is how i'd like my screen to look like when my mouse is on "blueGrey"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cceb8.png)

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes have the same issue. For me, when I open the Quick Documentation with CTRL Q (Command J on Mac), then it shows the color swatches like on your second picture.